# Translation of the sentence and its relation with the text in circle brackets

Tags: grammar, translation

I can't completely understand the second sentence, especially connecting the parts in circle brackets with the narration. I tried to make a translation, could somebody please check if I'm understanding something wrong?

Fast translation:
On the other hand, some part of her mind also felt strangely clear (Kei's death)(legend of a witch) (Munakata's family)(this school itself)(Aya and group) various thoughts(red...) gave birth to countless wheerpools(inside of mine...), merging with each other, and racking her tired heart(red...).

Does by various thoughts speaker means all of the facts before（恵の死）...?

> まだ七時だというのに、眠くて仕方なかった。一方ではしかし、妙に冴えた部分もあって（恵の死）（魔女の伝説）（宗像の家）（この学園そのもの）（綾たちのグループ）さまざまなもの思いが（赤い・・・・・・）いくつもの渦を作り（わたしの中の・・・・・・）お互いに絡み合い、疲れた心を揺り動かしている（緋い・・・・・・）。
>   もう寝てしまおう、と思った。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the words in parentheses are not directly related to the main sentence outside of them. And the words in parentheses are not strongly related with one another, either.

It must be a very rhetorical expression, simulating random ideas pops one after another in the character's mind, disturbing her sleep. The author basically wanted you to be confused just like the character in the story. Your translation seems to be fair enough to me.